# Using Django-import-export import of blank TextField

Tags: python, django, null, textfield, import-from-excel

Imagine I have data stored in my database. A model contains a Django TextField with `blank=True` but without `null=True` according to Django convention. The data were created via the `admin-menu`. Empty TextFields are stored as empty strings which works just fine. But import trough django-import-export throws `violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains`. Is this a problem of django-import-export?

Comment: In my imagination, the code to do this works perfectly. Unfortunately, it sounds like your code isn't the same as the code in my imagination. Please show us some code so we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing from excel, you will have to give empty string('') instead of empty columns in excel.